# Nelson-Aalen estimator in discrete time

Tags: survival, markov-process

I was wondering whether the Nelson-Aalen estimator can be applied to discrete-time multi-state data (in months). I ask this because it seems that literature tends to present it only in the continuous-time framework (in particular within the so called "counting processes" approach).

Since in discrete time data are incomplete (in the sense that they are interval-censored), I guess that it is necessary to assume non-informative interval censoring, in addition to the random right-censoring assumption.

Is this rigth? Can you suggest some literature about it?